# How to authorize request in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, post

I'm trying send any request to get my data in elastic search. I'm running docker with elastic search and kibana.

My url to acess elastic is: `http:192.168.1.102:9200`, and my crendentials are `username: 'elastic ',password: MagicWord`

I tried make request with passorwd and username: `http://elastic.Magic@ 192.168.1.102:9200/storedevent`, but it isn't work.

Do I need a token to acess elastic in postman?

***Print:***

[image: 401Unauthorized]

***Erro:***

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/storedevent]",
                "header": {
                    "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/storedevent]",
        "header": {
            "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
    },
    "status": 401
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postman you need to pass credentials in Basic Auth instead of url.[image]

Comment: Glad could be of  help.